# How to build the externally added jar in maven to make it work in Kubernetes

Tags: java, maven, kubernetes

I have added the jar in the path : root-project->lib->jumper.jar

POM.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>jump</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/jumper.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

this works locally but when deployed to Kubernetes it's not working

Comment: There it says `<scope>system</scope>` which means it's going to be provided by the system. Add the dependency on the classpath when running the app or add it to the jar you are building

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo could you please give some example

Comment: Found myself the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71794311/1089841

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of `<scope>system</scope>`. It's telling Maven that the library is gonna be loaded in the system.
To fix this issue, one thing you can do is generate a jar with all dependencies included using Maven plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>your.main.class.here</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

That plugin will generate a bigger jar than usual containing all the dependencies in it.

Now it's just simple as running the jar with `java -jar file.jar`

Comment: Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:' not found

Comment: After Adding <version> no errors

Comment: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/abc/JumpLine] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/abc/JumpLine

After updating like above mentioned still it's not workig

Comment: Make sure you are executing the `jar-with-dependencies` and not the one with no dependencies on it.